# Check if paths from file are physically located in hard drive

Tags: disk

Hello I have a file named files.txt in that file there are paths to files for example:
/home/ojom/123.jpg
/home/ojom/oaksdokwijeqijwqe.jpg

There is million of those paths in this file I need to see if the files in that file are physically located (exists) on my hard drive (if they don't write those paths to another file) how do I do that? What can I use?

Comment: Any programming language you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse that file using PHP and then go through the results and check them with `file_exists`.

The example below works if every file path is on a new line.

```
<?php

$files = array();
$handle = fopen("files.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if(!file_exits($line)) {
          continue; // file does not exist, skip
        } else {
          $files[] = $line;
        }
    }
} else {
    die('Error opening the file');
} 
fclose($handle);

echo "These files exist:";
echo "<pre>" . print_r($files, true) . "</pre>"; // prints them as an array
```

You could also use the array for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Python](https://www.python.org/) solution:

```
import os.path

files = 'c:\\test\\files.txt'
output = 'c:\\test\\filesNotExist.txt'

with open(files) as f:
    for file in f:
        if not os.path.isfile(file):
            f = open(output, 'w')
            f.write(file)
            f.close()
f.close()
```

This script scans your text file and writes list of non-existed files to the output text file.